# override fun onRequestPermissionsResult on other class

Tags: android, kotlin

I write the **Permission** class, here have the **askMicrophonePermission**
method.

In **askMicrophonePermission**, I use **ActivityCompat.requestPermissions**
function.

But I can't *override* **onRequestPermissionsResult** in **Permission**
class.

If I want *override* **onRequestPermissionsResult** in **Permission**, not
in **MainActivity**.

How to write?? Here is my code.

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Permission().askMicrophonePermission(this@MainActivity)
    }
}
```

Permission:

```
class Permission{
    private val tag = "Permission message"
    private val userMicrophonePermissionAgreeCode = 1

    fun askMicrophonePermission(context: Context){

        val currentMicrophonePermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)


        if(currentMicrophonePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context as Activity, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO), userMicrophonePermissionAgreeCode)
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        when(requestCode){
            userMicrophonePermissionAgreeCode -> {
                if( grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED )
                    Log.i(tag,"Agree microphone permission")
                else
                    Log.i(tag,"Not agree microphone permission")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`onRequestPermissionsResult` is a method from `FragmentActivity`. Since your `Permission` doesn't extend `FragmentActivity`, you cannot override `onRequestPermissionsResult` directly in the `Permission`.

You can delegate permission results to `Permission`.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var permission: Permission

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        permission = Permission()
        permission.askMicrophonePermission(this@MainActivity)
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        permission.handlePermissionsResult(resquestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    }
}
```

Permission:

```
class Permission{
    private val tag = "Permission message"
    private val userMicrophonePermissionAgreeCode = 1

    fun askMicrophonePermission(context: Context){

        val currentMicrophonePermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)


        if(currentMicrophonePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context as Activity, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO), userMicrophonePermissionAgreeCode)
    }

    fun handlePermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        when(requestCode){
            userMicrophonePermissionAgreeCode -> {
                if( grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED )
                    Log.i(tag,"Agree microphone permission")
                else
                    Log.i(tag,"Not agree microphone permission")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just Extend Fragment Activity on Permission Class**

```
class Permission() : FragmentActivity()
```

**How I have done in my project**

```
class AskPermission(val activity:Activity): FragmentActivity() {

private val code: Int =0

fun ask(context: Context, permission: String) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context,
            permission
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Already Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show()
    } else {
        requestStoragePermission(context)
    }
}

private fun requestStoragePermission(context: Context) {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
            activity,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        )
    ) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context as Activity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),code)
    }
    else
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context as Activity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),code)
    }
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: any idea how to do kotlin code for flutter to seek permission. Is it Same?